# codeigniter captcha helper , how to save data in DB when IP address is dynamic?

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, helper

hi i am using **codeigniter captcha** helper , i used this guide .

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html

but every time i got my entered **captcha** as incorrect .

i checked this query .

```
// Then see if a captcha exists:
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM captcha WHERE word = ? AND ip_address = ? AND captcha_time > ?";
$binds = array($_POST['captcha'], $this->input->ip_address(), $expiration);
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $binds);
$row = $query->row();
```

then i checked my `$this->input->ip_address()` , every time it varies , that's why i can not get the correct data , i tried to do using a session , but server does not saving sessions  , how can i check the captcha code now , please help , thanks in advance

Comment: pass the unique token back as a form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a random token and storing it in the database and then passing it to the client, have the client pass it back and compare it to the token you stored in the database.